# ASP.net "{Controller}/" returning 403.14 error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, routes, http-error

I am having a curious issue with one of my projects in development. The issue is with links to a certain URL "//localhost:62168/Images/Index". I have buttons linking to that URL but when "//localhost:62168/Images/" is accessed it returns a HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden error. See the below Image:

[localhost//Images/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VMYu.png)

Oddly enough though, when I enter the URL exactly ("localhost:62168/Images/Index") it loads the page properly. See the below Image:

[localhost/Images/Index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7psu.jpg)

I've done plenty of research online and I believe it may be an issue with routing so below I've added the code of my "RouteConfig.cs" file. Unfortunately, I am new to ASP.net and MVC and not knowledgeable on proper Routing procedures:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace ReedHampton
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried multiple other "solutions" presented in other online forums to no avail. These include:

1. Adding "directoryBrowse enabled="true" " to web.config
2. Running "C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319> aspnet_regiis.exe -i" in Command Prompt
3. Going through IIS Express and registering IIS Express and ASP.Net

I would greatly appreciate any help that anyone can provide!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIS will attempt to short-circuit the request if it finds something on the filesystem that matches the URL. In other words, I'd assume you have an `Images` directory in your document root. Therefore, IIS will attempt to hit this directory, rather than pass the request on to the ASP.NET machinery. Since you've disabled directory browsing, you get a 403.

Long and short, you need to keep your ASP.NET MVC routes unique from what you have physically in your document root. You could change the name of the `Images` directory to something like `img`, or put it in a parent folder like the default of `/Content/Images`. Otherwise, you'll need to change your controller name or create a custom route to that controller not called `/Images`.

Comment: This was exactly the issue. The folder that I stored my images in was called "Images". Changing the name of that folder resolved my issue! Also, I read your guide for adding Image uploads and it was extraordinarily helpful, thanks so much!!!!