# Controller name conflicts with folders inside project solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I've created a controller named "Services" which works fine except that the default action not working. More specifically when I try to reach `.../Services` I get the

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

error but `.../Services/Index` works. All other controllers are working fine. What am I doing wrong or is there any reserved routes or something like that? I have removed the "IgnoreRoute" in `RouteConfig` but still not working.

This is the controllers code:

```cs
public class ServicesController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    // GET: Services
    public ActionResult Index(int CategoryId = -1)
    {
        if (CategoryId == -1)
        {
            var services = db.Services.Include(s => s.ServiceCategory).Include( i => i.Images);
            return View(services.ToList());
        }
        else
        {
            var services = db.Services.Where(r => r.ServiceCategoryId == CategoryId).Include(p => p.ServiceCategory).Include(i => i.Images);
            return View(services.ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

And the route config:

```cs
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
I found the cause, I have a folder named "Services" inside project's solution. But I think that this behavior is not acceptable, so my question is what's the solution for this?

Comment: I created a project with what you have, I mean you controller , it works fine.

Comment: I think this link helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44932387/asp-net-controller-returning-403-14-error

Comment: Thank you, I found the cause meanwhile and edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need it to set `RouteExistingFiles` to `true` in `RouteConfig` class.

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```

The simplest way might be renaming your folder to something else in order to avoid this conflict.

Answer (score 0):

You must change the virtual directory in the project

like this 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IQXV.png